[AX2012R3]How to import a password protected Excel file
I need import excel file but it has password protect file and alright i have password
but how to define password in x++
i need import file with enter password via x++
My code
    pathName = strFmt('%1',PathCtrl.Text());
    excel       = SysExcelApplication::construct();
    workbooks   = excel.workbooks();

    try
    { 
        workbooks.open(@pathName);

        workbook    = workbooks.item(1);
        worksheets  = workbook.worksheets();
        worksheet   = worksheets.itemFromNum(3);
        cells       = worksheet.cells();
        type        = cells.item(row+1, 1).value().variantType();
        record_count     = this.findLastRow(worksheet);
        _Progress.setTotal(record_count);

        while (type != COMVariantType::VT_EMPTY)
        {
            row++;

            info(strFmt("%1",cells.item(row,1).value().bStr()));

            type    = cells.item(row+1, 1).value().variantType();
            _Progress.setText(strFmt("%1 : %2 / %3",cells.item(row, 2).value().bStr(),row,record_count));
            _Progress.setCount(row);
            _Progress.update(true);
        }
        excel.quit();
    }
    catch (Exception::Error)
    {

        excel.quit();
        throw error("File cannot be opened");
    }


You input the password(s) when you open the workbook on this line:

workbooks.open(@pathName);

Change to something like:
workbooks.open(@pathName, 0, false, 5, 'OpenDocPassword', 'WriteDocPassword');
Look at \Classes\SysExcelWorkbooks_XP\open for the function declaration.

Thanks you. It dose work. finally why put '@' in front parameter?

I just copied and pasted your code. You only put @ in front of a string literal to have it ignore escape characters. No clue why your code had it like that, but if you had myPath = "C:\MyFile.xlsx", it wouldn't work because "" is an escape character. If you did myPath = @"C:\MyFile.xlsx" (note the @), then it takes it as a literal and works fine.
